# Javacript track opened windows's particular button click and status code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, twitter, tracking

In my app, there is a twitter share buttion. I want to track if a user shared the post or not.

Currently, it is opening a windows with the text and when a user tweet the post and then they can close the windows.

I want to track two event:

1. if they click on tweet button
2. the status of code when user click on `tweet` buttion on twittr share windows

Here is my code:

```
const shareTwitter = () => {
   
    url = window.location.href
    var url = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=some text goes here`
    var child = window.open(url,  '','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436')
    var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

    function checkChild() {
        if (child.closed) {
          alert("You have succesfully shared")
         
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
  
  }
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to do? if possible, how can i do it?

I apprecaite for your time